# MVC Kendo UI Grid - 100 + columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo UI GRID (MVC) with 100+ columns.
Not all the columns are visible on load. The default columns visible are 10.
There are checkboxes on the page, next to the grid, which list all the columns. If you click on a checkbox, depending on whether it is checked or unchecked, the column appears or is hidden.
The trouble is that the grid takes almost 20 seconds to render, when the number of rows is also huge (and the time increases).
What is the best way to handle a large number of columns?

Comment: Is your grid paged at all ?

Comment: it is paged, client side. I did try sever side paging but the performance gain isn't signifiant

Comment: really more than 100? whats the point to show all of that information.. even your screen can't show all that columns at once, you should use horizontal scroll in this case..

Comment: Well, the customer wants an excel sheet like look and feel with all the columns across forms in one table.

Comment: @AnthonyFernandes you could explore other alternatives like [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/products/flexsheet/)

Comment: Thank you, yes I think that would be a good option!

Answer (score 0):

I think that bring all the 100 columns for a record is not the best way to work. Maybe you must most important information (10 column at max) for all the records and have a detailed view (with the rest of the information for the specific record you want to inspect)

If you want to see a more detailed example take a look [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate)

my approach is the following

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YOURCLASS>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.imporantColumn1);
        columns.Bound(e => e.imporantColumn2);
        columns.Bound(e => e.imporantColumn3);            
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_theBasicData", "Grid"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
```

and a detailed template

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("tabStrip_#=ID#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("details").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<YOURCLASS>()
                        .Name("grid_#=ID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            // the order columns
                        })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_theRestOfInfo", "Grid", new { ID= "#=ID#" }))
                        )
                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .ToClientTemplate())
                </text>                        
                );               
            })
            .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, we did think of this but the customer wants more of an excel look and feel with a single row per record, rather than a drill down.